# how to resolve PhoneAuthOptions symbol

Tags: android

PhoneAuthOptions option = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(firebaseAuth);

```
              .setphoneNumber(phoneNumber);

              .setTimeout(60l, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

              .setActivity(MainActivity.this);

              .setCallbacks(mCallBack);

              .build();
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ok there is a problem on the PhoneAuthOptions... i am told that to resolve the symbol..

Answer (score 0):

use this dependencies

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.7'